# Python Read Binary vs NodeJS Read Binary

Tags: python, node.js, png

I have a method in a Python REST service that expects binary contents of an image file that it extracts and saves it to a file that can later be opened as a valid image file:

```
@require_http_module(['POST'])
def my_method(request)
  image_data = request.FILES['image']
  fs.save('image.png', image_data)
```

If I send a request at this service via a Python script, it works fine:

```
import requests
image_file = '......image.png'
image_data = open(image_file, 'rb')
requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/...', files = dict(image = image_data))
```

If, however, I use NodeJS to dispatch a request at the Python service, it doesn't work properly:

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import FormData from 'form-data';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
const IMAGE_DATA = readFileSync('......image.png', { encoding: 'binary' });
const FORM_DATA = new FormData();
FORM_DATA.append('image', IMAGE_DATA, { filename: 'image.png' });
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/...', { method: 'POST', body: FORM_DATA });
```

Opening the image files saved by the Python service for both these requests in VSCode as binary data makes the reason clear: Encoding/Charset differences between the two clients.

[image]

The window on the right is the PNG file sent by Python script and saved by the Python service.

The window on the left is the PNG file sent by NodeJS script and saved by the Python service.

Is there a way to fix this in NodeJS?

**EDIT**

Upon further testing, I found out that the following:

```
const IMAGE_DATA_1 = readFileSync('imageSource.png', { encoding: 'binary' });
writeFileSync('imageDest1.png', IMAGE_DATA_1);
// THE FILE imageDest1.png CONTAINS BAD DATA AND CANNOT BE OPENED IN A GRAPHICS PROGRAM

const IMAGE_DATA_2 = readFileSync('imageSource.png');
writeFileSync('imageDest2.png', IMAGE_DATA_2);
// THE FILE imageDest2.png CONTAINS VALID DATA AND CAN BE OPENED IN A GRAPHICS PROGRAM
```

So the solution was to not use `{ encoding: 'binary' }` flags. However, I would've thought that image files contain binary data and should be opened with `binary` encoding. So why is this causing issues?